# how to represent a list of U.S. States

Tags: c#, asp.net, nunit, fluentvalidation

Trying to do TDD against FluentValidation and Looking for the proper way to represent a list of US States.

For example, I have an "Address" object.

I would like to write a test (and a FluentValidation rule) that declares the address invalid if it's not in a list of US States.

This is a finite list, only to include the 50 US States, so I think it should be something constant and not represented in a database.

What I'm wondering is, what is the most efficient way to store and validate/test against this? An enum, an array, a list object, what?

Comment: some hints: don't duplicate a tag like "C#" in your titles. Just leave them in the tags. Also, please leave out "Hello", "Thanks", etc. This is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.

Comment: The are other valid US addresses than the 50 states.  Washington, DC for example.  Also Puerto Rico.  Check out the complete list from USPS:  http://www.usps.com/ncsc/lookups/usps_abbreviations.html.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `static readonly` array or HashSet.

A state can be represented by it's full name or it's abbreviation.  Do you want to check for both?  Also, a state can be validated by a zip code (I'm not sure if you want to do that though).

You could possibly have a static readonly single-array or a hashset containing both the full name and abbreviation, like this:

```
public static readonly string[] listOfStates = new string[]
    {
        "New York",
        "NY",
        // rest of states & abbreviations here...
    };
```

or

```
public static readonly HashSet<string> listOfStates = new HashSet<string>
    {
        "New York",
        "NY",
        // rest of states & abbreviations here...
    };
```

Both support the `Contains` syntax:

```
// Queryable like this:
bool stateMatch = listOfStates.Contains(stringValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with keeping them in a constant string array...

```
//Define the constant array
const String[] TheStates = new String[] { "Alabama", "Arizona", ... };

//fluentvalidation rule
RuleFor(address => address.State).Must(theState => TheStates.Contains(theState));
```

Keeping them in an `Enum` would require some association between the state name and an integer value - it just doesn't sound as efficient.  Or you'd have to use `ToString()` a lot or build some custom attribute for each item in your enum (I've seen a few examples of this - but then you're dealing with reflection, which isn't as performant).

I would consider a `List` only if you need some additional data with each state (e.g. Full Name, Abbreviation, Date Admitted, etc.).

Go with the simplest format that you can.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The first line of the example won't work in c#.  You'll get this error:  **A const field of a reference type other than string can only be initialized with null.**